# How to transform this piece-wise function (basic)?

Tags: trigonometry

[The problem and piece-wise function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYiXm.png) (rendered into MathJax below)

The current $I(t)$ in an LC series circuit is goverened by the initial value problem
\begin{equation}
I^{\prime\prime}(t)+4I(t)=g(t),\quad I(0)=1,I^\prime(0)=3
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
g(t)=\begin{cases}
3\sin t,&\quad 0\le t\le2\pi\\
0,&\quad 2\pi<t
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Determine the current as a function of time.\

\textit{Solution}: Since

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\{I^{\prime\prime}\}(s)=s\mathcal{L}\{I\}(s)-s-3,
\end{equation}
we obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{L}\{I^{\prime\prime} \}(s)+4\mathcal{L}\{I\}(s)&=&
s\mathcal{L}\{I\}(s)-s-3+4\mathcal{L}\{I\}(s)\\
&=&(s^2+4)\mathcal{L}\{I\}(s)-(s+3)\\
&=&\mathcal{L}\{g\}(s).
\end{eqnarray}

To compute $\mathcal{L}\{g\}(s)$, note that

\begin{equation}
g(t)=3(\sin t-(\sin t)u(t-2\pi))
\end{equation}

Above is the problem (not necessarily relevant) but in the picture is where the g(t) function is changed. I guess I need to brush up on algebra... Is there a formula for this change that is used or a name of the specific concept I'm forgetting?

Comment: $u (t)=0 $ if $t\le 0$ and $u (t)=1$ if $t>0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $u$ is called the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). It is useful to model signals that switch on, to construct step functions, etc. And has well known distributional derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering a piecewise function into an expression using the Heaviside function $U(t)$, use the following pattern:

$g(t)=\begin{cases} p(t) &0<t<c_1\\
q(t) & c_1<t<c_2\\
r(t) & c_2<t
\end{cases}$

then

$$g(t)=p(t)+[q(t)-p(t)]U(t-c_1)+[r(t)-q(t)]U(t-c_2)$$

In this instance this gives

\begin{eqnarray}g(t)&=&3\sin(t)+[0-3\sin(t)]U(t-2\pi)\\
&=&3\sin(t)-3\sin(t)U(t-2\pi)
\end{eqnarray}